# Is it possible to automatically clear unused areas of a texture map with default Blender tools?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I'm a very basic noob in Blender, and I've been unable to find a solution to my goals.

I have a basic model and I'm adding a texture, so far so good. The screenshot is a mock-up, not the real thing, but it serves a purpose.

There is often a lot of wasted space in a texture, so it looks something like this:

[image: Example image of wasted space in texture / uv map]

I see some lovely uvmaps, with nice clear space around them, like this:

[image: Clear space around uv coords]

My question is, essentially, how can I achieve something more like the gun model uv map / texture using default or freely available Blender tools for 2.79 or 2.80?

Comment: You can manually paint the unused area white in the uv/image editor, but there is no easy select and delete.

Comment: Thanks...I think, having investigated this a bit more, I can bake it to get rid of unreferenced areas. This is not an answer yet though.